# How to lock recurred in edit mode from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I tried this code but after applied `function Block Record()` you can change row value

```
public void BlockRecord()
{
    using (db = new BookContext())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    " SELECT Price FROM Books WITH (UPDLOCK)" +
                    " WHERE BookID = 3");
    }
}

public void Update()
{
    using (db = new BookContext())
    {
        var result = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookID == 3);

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Price = result.Price + 1;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

Operations op = new Operations();
op.BlockRecord();
op.Update();
```

Comment: locks don't work that way -- they just apply to the query running.  To protect against changes you need to use user rights -- eg a user which has only read access.

Comment: How to lock record in edit mode from entity framework ...?

Comment: This would be better handled where the saving of data takes place, perhaps a single point for updates and a single point for inserts, using guards.

Comment: The **strongly preferred way** is to use "optimistic concurrency" - you **do NOT** place any locks, since in most system, the chance of really two people changing the same record is extremely small. You change, and then on `.SaveChanges()`, you have to be prepared to handle potential `OptimisticConcurrencyException` that occurs if a row has really been changed in the meantime. That's much easier, and fully supported by EF out of the box - embrace that approach!

Comment: For more details, see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application and many, many more articles and tutorials on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

Locks don't work this way in SQL., they just apply to the query running.

To protect against changes you need to use user rights -- eg a user which has only read access.

Another option is to add business rules to your code.  For example considering the following rules:

Every table has a `lockme` column:

- When that column is set to 1 then no one can change the row.
- When that column is set to 0 then anyone can change the row.

If this was your rule then you could add the following code to every update query

```
 UPDATE -- etc
 WHERE lockme <> 1
```

As long as every update (and delete statement) had this where then you could be sure locked rows would not be deleted or updated.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, it's preferred to use optimistic concurrency in EF, as it allows you to detect and resolve concurrency issues without holding long-lived locks, or using native SQL commands.

What you propose *will* work, but the two operations need to be composed in a transaction.  The duration of the UPDLOCK is otherwise just a single statement.  The simplest change to your posted code would be to introduce a TransactionScope in the calling code.

So first add a helper method to properly configure a TransactionScope for SQL Server:

```
  public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
  {
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
  }
```

then:

```
using (var tran = CreateTransactionScope())
{
  Operations op = new Operations();
  op.BlockRecord();
  op.Update();
  tran.Complete();
}
```

Alternatively you can implement the Unit-of-work pattern in your `Operations` class, having its members share a DbContext instance and add a SaveChanges() or similar method to it.